# How to get an AVCapture Timecode?

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapture

I'm working on a video capture app using the AVFoundation framework, based on the [AVCam](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112) sample by Apple. I'd like to implement functionality to set a maximum video length, and have the capture automatically stops when this limit is reached (similar to [UIImagePickerController.videoMaximumDuration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/videoMaximumDuration)).

I'm assuming I need to register for some notification as the capture is recording, and to check the timestamp in this callback. I looked through the AV Foundation Programming Guide and did a bit of Googling, and I can't find a way to retrieve the elapsed time of a AVCaptureSession, AVCaptureMovieFileOutput, or AVCaptureSomethingElse.

Any insight would help. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the presentation time stamp of the incoming CMSampleBuffers? Oh wait, you don't say how you're capturing. Are you using AVCaptureMovieFileOutput or AVCaptureVideoDataOutput?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `maxRecordedDuration` or `maxRecordedFileSize`. However, you need to make sure you handle the error correctly on the `captureOutput:didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:fromConnections:error:` delegate call to detect whether the recording stopped due to an error or due to reaching max duration/file size.

check the error code like:

```
if (([error code] == AVErrorMaximumDurationReached)) {
    [delegate captureSessionMaxDurationReached];
}
```